# Ordenar lista simplemente enlazada Quicksort

Tags: c, lista, ordenamiento

Hola he estado intentando ordenar una lista simplemente enlazada mediante el algoritmo de quicksort pero no me la ordena correctamente . Me he quedado un poco atorado ya que no encuentro el problema

```
void quicksort(COLUMN *V, ETIQUETA* izq, ETIQUETA*  der)
{
  char*p;
  ETIQUETA* i;
  ETIQUETA* d;
  ETIQUETA* pivote;
  ETIQUETA*e=V->lista;
  strcpy(p,seleccionar_pivote(V, izq, der));

  if (p != NULL)
  {
      while(e!=NULL)
              {
                  if(strcmp(p,e->etiqueta)==0)
                  {
                      pivote->etiqueta=e->etiqueta;
                      pivote->cuenta=e->cuenta;
                      pivote->siguiente=e->siguiente;
                      break;
                  }
                  e=e->siguiente;
              }
      i=izq;
      d=der;
      while(strcmp(i->etiqueta,d->etiqueta)<=0)
      {
          while(strcmp(i->etiqueta,pivote->etiqueta)<0)
          {
              i=i->siguiente;
          }

          while(strcmp(d->etiqueta,pivote->etiqueta)>0)
          {
              d=d->siguiente;
          }

          if(strcmp(i->etiqueta,d->etiqueta)<=0)
          {
              intercambiar(V,i,d);
              i=i->siguiente;
              d=d->siguiente;
          }
      }

      if(strcmp(izq->etiqueta,d->etiqueta)<0)
          quicksort(V, izq,d);
      if(strcmp(i->etiqueta,der->etiqueta)<0)
          quicksort(V, i,der);
  }
}

char* seleccionar_pivote(COLUMN *V, ETIQUETA* izq, ETIQUETA* der)
{
  ETIQUETA*cen=Medio(V->lista);

  if(((strcmp(izq->etiqueta,cen->etiqueta)<=0) && (strcmp(izq->etiqueta,der->etiqueta)>=0)) || ((strcmp(izq->etiqueta,cen->etiqueta)>=0) && (strcmp(izq->etiqueta,der->etiqueta)<=0)))
  {
      return izq->etiqueta;
  }
  else if((strcmp(cen->etiqueta,izq->etiqueta)<=0 && strcmp(cen->etiqueta,der->etiqueta)>=0) || (strcmp(cen->etiqueta,izq->etiqueta)>=0 && strcmp(cen->etiqueta,der->etiqueta)<=0))
  {
      return cen->etiqueta;
  }
  else
  {
      return der->etiqueta;
  }

  
}

ETIQUETA* Medio(ETIQUETA*e){
  ETIQUETA*l=e;
  int n=0;
  int i;
  while(e!=NULL){
      n++;
      l=l->siguiente;
  }
  //Volveos al principio
  l=e;
  //Calculamos la mosicion media
  n=n/2;
  //Obtenemos la posición media
  for ( i=0;i<n;i++){
      l=l->siguiente;
  }
  return l;
}

void intercambiar(COLUMN * V, ETIQUETA * izq, ETIQUETA * der)
{

  ETIQUETA *e=V->lista;   
  while(e!=NULL){
          //Comprobamos si la etiqueta izquierda está en la lista
                  if(strcmp(izq->etiqueta,e->etiqueta)==0)
                  {
                      //Ponemos la etiqueta derecha en la posición de la izquierda
                      strcpy(e->etiqueta,der->etiqueta);
                      e->cuenta=der->cuenta;
                      break;
                  }
                  //Pasamos al siguiente nodo de la lista
                  e=e->siguiente;
              }
  //continuamos para encontrar la de la derecha ya que estará mas alejada que la de la izquierda
  
  while(e!=NULL){
                  if(strcmp(der->etiqueta,e->etiqueta)==0)
                  {
                      strcpy(e->etiqueta,izq->etiqueta);
                      e->cuenta=izq->cuenta;
                      break;
                  }
                  e=e->siguiente;
              }
  V->lista=e;
}
```

He podido ordenarla mediante otros métodos pero me gustaría aportarle mayor valor haciéndolo mediante este.
aquí dejo las estructuras:

```
typedef enum {VOID, NUM, DATE, STR} TIPO;

// Estructura: ETIQUETA
typedef struct etiq {
    char *etiqueta;          
    int cuenta;              
    struct etiq * siguiente; 
} ETIQUETA;

// Estructura: COLUMNA
typedef struct col {
    char *nom;            
    TIPO t;               
    ETIQUETA *lista;      
    struct col *next;     
} COLUMN;`
```

En este código tengo una lista enlazada dentro de otra pero solo me interesa ordenar la lista con el nombre de etiqueta   el caso es que cuando el algoritmo actúa parece que se queda a la mitad igual el hecho de intentar adaptar un algoritmo que funciona con vectores numéricos no es la mejor idea ,por favor ayuda , no se que es lo que esta mal o la forma de hacerlo